# Unable to add users into sharepoint if i am Using emails as account name in Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, active-directory

I am using moss 2007 version 12.0.0.6421. and Active directory version 6.0.. . my AD domain is siamint so if i add a user as vikas. it gets added in AD with logon name as vikas@siamint.com now if i add a user sahil@yahoo.com into ad. it gets added as sahil@yahoo.com@siamint. now when i try to add user from peoples and groups,site settings in a sharepoint site; i gets user siamint\sahil in people picker. rather it should be siamint\sahil@yahoo.com. it means the name is truncated from @. Is this a sharepoint error or what. Ultimately i think it means we cannot add users with @ in their usernames.

Comment: and if i add that user the following error comes:The user does not exist or is not unique.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32 lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object& pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object& pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bSendEmail) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32 lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object& pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object& pvarArrayIdsR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a user to Active-Directory you give a "*user session Name*" (1) which is composed with the domain name (2) to give an attribute which is the real login name stored in an attribute called "*userPrincipalName*".

[image]

So "jpb@dom.fr" in the preceding picture **IS NOT** a mail adress but the UPN (userPrincipalName) of your user in Active-Directory.

Since Windows 2000 UPN is supposed to replace the old login string (3)

---

**Edited**

[image: user Creation with @]

Sorry, it's in french, but as you can see '@' is allowed in the logon part of the UPN. Look in [Microsoft documentation (Active directory naming) for more information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739093%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: But what if i give user session name as: jpb@yahoo.com then UPN should become jpb@yahoo.com@dom.fr Now my problem is that when i try to access this user in sharepoint to add it to a site, it still picks it as jpb and not jpb@yahoo.com which is the actual user session name.

Comment: Sorry, as you can see in in the screen copy I add, @ is not allowef in the login name.

Comment: so it means, i cannot use email as login name if i am using Active Directory as Membership Provider in my website.

Comment: You just can see which characters are not allowed in the logon part of Active-Directory.